# Does a DomainService load all entities before executing linq?

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, linq, silverlight

My Silverlight application uses RIA Webservices to interact with a `DomainService` which uses an Entity Framework Model.

In the service I have something simple like:

```
Public Function GetCompanyByID(companyID As Integer) As Company
    Return ObjectContext.Companies.FirstOrDefault(Function(c) c.ID = companyID)
End Function
```

My question is are all the companies loaded from the database first, and then queried with LINQ and sent to the client?

I am asking because the database may grow, and some eager loading of some navigation properties within the company entity might be introduced. Hence it may take a long time to load all companies first.

Answer (score 0):

RIA ObjectContext operates IQueryable. You can return IQueryable from your methods domain service methods to allow client side 'linq to client model entities' translated to server side 'linq to entities/db' (lazy by default) via expression tree serialization. You can anable eager loading by [turning off 'LazyLoadingEnabled'](http://madsdevblog.blogspot.ru/2011/02/eager-loading-ef4-entities-with-ria.html).

See also   about [Code-First in RIA (DbContext)](http://varunpuranik.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/wcf-ria-services-support-for-ef-4-1-and-ef-code-first/) - **this is how you can fully support/control your choice of ORM**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is C# version

```
        var exp1=this.ObjectContext.snv_patient;
        var expression = exp1.FirstOrDefault((item) => item.Id == patientID);
```

When you write

```
       (exp1 as System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery).ToTraceString()
```

it returns an sql quering **all the data on the table**

But the second one expression can't be cast to ObjectQuery so it seems predicate applying each element. It doesn't seem good.

Lets profile it ! When I profile this operation I see that the executing query is

```
  "SELECT`Extent1`.`Id`, `Extent1`.`CitizenNo`,..some othre fields.
    FROM `snv_patient` AS `Extent1`
     WHERE `Extent1`.`Id` = 3 LIMIT 1"
```

ID is patientID in my query (3) .So this extension method firstly turn to SQL then execute. So its safe. Firstly turn to SQL. Then Enumerate it.

You may also use Where extension sure. I always prefere Where(p=p.patientID==3).FirstOrDefault()